# Am I automatically considered to be following one whom I connect through LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

I've just found that I'm following all people whom I connected to.

There are two ways to connect people through LinkedIn 1. Send an invitation and 2. Accept an invitation. Either way you connect the people I think it is also considered following automatically.

- So, Is connecting people automatically consider following them upon connection? Can I stop it? or I've to manually manage it individually?
- I've found that you can also follow one without connecting. Similarly you can unfollow one whom you're connected with.
- What is the difference between connecting people and following people?

Note that I'm talking about peoples only not about following groups or companies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinkedIn defines a connection as a two-way relationship of trust between people who know each other. If you are connected to someone, you’re following him or her by default and vice-versa.

So yes, to unfollow anyone you have to manually manage it individually.

Yes, you can follow anyone to get their updates on your home page. Once you follow them they will get notification about it. They will not get any update from you if they are not following you. You can unfollow anyone anytime. They will not get notification about it.

See the LinkedIn Help to know about [Similarities and Differences Between Following And Connecting](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/32504/similarities-and-differences-between-following-and-connecting?lang=en).